# Custom brush texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In my document I have an olive leaf (top part of the picture), which I'd need to repeat so it would look like in the middle part of the picture. Leaves size and angle would need to vary a bit (something like = size +/-20% and angle +/-5°).
Bottom part was created by brush preset taken from the top part, which is easy to use and the result looks how I want it, except it doesn't keep the texture from the original but only one color and there's some transparency where leaves overlap.
I've created middle section by - duplicate the leaf layer, transform, change size, angle, repeat... which was annoyingly slow.
Is there a faster, easier way how to do that?

[image: leaves]

Answer (score 1):

Check your brush presets, this is the best way to do it. You can just remove opacity from the brush in the toolbar and reduce amount of leaves (Spacing) and it will look just like the middle one.